# Building a string from an array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string-conversion

This is the array i've received in my controller from doing a POST which is built dynamically based on the number of inputs given by the user.
[image: sample_array]

I would like to convert it into a string in my controller which would produce something like "test3 or test2 or test" to use in a PHP exec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode(' or ', $array['emailVal'])
```